# Position absolute vs overflow hidden

Tags: css

Why my div positioned as absolute didn't get out of the flow and get hidden by a mom div her overflow set to hidden ?
How can i show my div positioned to absolute ?
here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3zVJu/)

HTML :

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">        
        <div class="div3">ccccc</div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.div1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 60px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.div2 {
    position: relative;
}

.div3 {
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Try `right:-50px;`, it hides then.

Comment: i want to show it not hide it

Comment: Don't use `overflow:hidden;` then.

Comment: i have to use it in my big code

Comment: Its not positioned as absolute. remove this -> right: -10px;

Comment: my friend i want a answer not change my default property because i know if i remove `right: -10px;` it works but in my big code i have to use this property like in the question

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your "div3" class.

Try this:

```
.div3 {
    position: absolute;
}
```

That should fit nicely.

Now if you want it to be centered, then just go:

```
.div3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

EDIT:
If you insist, then the easiest will be to have a counter on the same element. Try this then:

```
.div3 {
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: no i want show the entire div3 in this possition `right: -10px;`

Comment: @Youssef - So, in other words, the padding then needs to be equal and opposite to the amount of the 'right offset'.